# DB2 convert long value to timestamp

Tags: db2, timestamp

Is there a scalar function in DB2 to convert a long number to TIMESTAMP?

Comment: The short answer is no.  You will have to do your own conversion, and it depends on what format your input data is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Dan1111 points out; no, there's nothing built in.

However, if you've got a 'long' number (I'm assuming `BIGINT`), I'm guessing you have a count of seconds (or similar) from the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC).  If so, it's easy to 'cheat', and you can use this logic to write your own:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', '00:00:00') + <your_column> SECONDS
FROM <your_table>
```

This of course presumes that the count is actually from UTC (and that you plan to interpret the results as such), as daylight savings time (and timezones, to a lesser extent) screws things up royally.

---

A quick example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01', '00:00:00') + 1348241581 SECONDS                                      
FROM sysibm/sysdummy1
```

Yields the expected:

```
2012-09-21-15.33.01.000000
```

(GMT, obviously)

Comment: Add the `CURRENT TIMEZONE` system variable to convert to local time.

Comment: @Stavr00 - When you're dealing with absolute times, it's better to work in UTC, and only translate when you go to display it (if necessary).